# Can Connect to OpenVPN but no internet access

Tags: 14.04, networking, vpn, openvpn

I have set up an openvpn server, generated a certificate and downloaded it to my client machine.

After importing the client.ovpn file in the network manager, I can still ssh into the server itself, but cannot access the internet.

In my sever's openvpn *server.conf*, I have:

```
 push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
 push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
 push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
```

all uncommented.

In the global *sysctl.conf* file I also have:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Is there anything I am missing configuration wise? What can I do to help debug the problem?

Comment: Where can't you access the Internet?  On your client or on the server?

Comment: Client, the server can access it fine

Comment: Could you give the output to `route` on the client before and after connecting to the server?  Please [edit] your question to provise this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to add this to `/etc/rc.local`

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to $MY_IP
```

Which probably would have shown up had I checked out `route` earlier!

Comment: Server's `/etc/rc.local` or client's?

Comment: To the server's.

Comment: Any chance you can explain why we need this on the server side? What does it do?